# Why the httpwebresponse ContentType is empty all the time ? Or most of the times

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I'm not getting any exceptions but most of the times now this line:

```
if (response.ContentType == "")
```

most of the times the ContentType is empty it's ""

My question is why ? And if there is any way to solve it ?
My program every 5 minutes downloading a file using this method.

This is how i call the method:

```
fileDownloadRadar(remote_image_on_server, combinedTemp);
```

remote_image_on_server is a string and contain: http://www.ims.gov.il/Ims/Pages/RadarImage.aspx?Row=9&TotalImages=10&LangID=1&Location=

combinedTemp is also a string: c:\test\test.gif

And this is the method:

```
HttpWebRequest request;
        int currentIndex = 0;
        void fileDownloadRadar(string uri, string fileName)
        {
            if (splash != null)
            {
                if (!splash.IsDisposed)
                    splash.UpdateProgressBar(0);
            }
            try
            {
                request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);
                request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {

                    long contentLength = response.ContentLength;
                    if (response.ContentType == "")
                    {
                        Logger.Write("ContentType is Empty download was not fine !!!!!");
                    }
                    if ((response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ||
                        response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Moved ||
                        response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect) &&
                        response.ContentType.StartsWith("image", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        Logger.Write("ContentType is not empty meaning download is fine");
                        using (Stream inputStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                        using (Stream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
                        {
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                            int bytesRead;
                            do
                            {
                                bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                currentIndex += bytesRead;
                                double percentage = (double)currentIndex / contentLength;
                                if (splash != null)
                                {
                                    if (!splash.IsDisposed)
                                        splash.UpdateProgressBar((int)(percentage * 100));
                                }
                                outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            } while (bytesRead != 0);
                            if (splash != null)
                            {
                                if (!splash.IsDisposed)
                                {
                                    splash.UpdateProgressBar(100);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        timer1.Stop();
                        timer3.Start();
                    }
                    if (splash == null)
                        FinishWebRequest();
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
                {
                    Logger.Write(ex.Status.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is an issue with the server.  If you're getting something other than a 200, that should be your starting point.

If you're getting a 200, try to duplicate the behavior outside of the code.  For example, use a plug-in to auto-refresh a browser and watch the responses.